# Localizing LaunchScreen.xib

Tags: ios, localization, launch-screen

So I've 2 different versions of my LaunchScreen.xib and I figured that by localizing the file it'd decide to use the right one at the right moment. However it does not. How can I make this happen?

There's no code because this is done in the interface builder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a proper way to do that. 
I would suggest you move to a LaunchScreen storyboard file, have no text there and have the Initial View Controller pretend to be an 'Extended Launch Screen'.

That way you could manipulate, localise and animate the view and have better control.

Static Launch Screen -> Extended Launch Screen (Initial View Controller) - > Animate to next View controller (Main App)

Answer (score 0):

The different xib will be used regarding the phone language. If you set your iPhone language to Chinese, `LaunchScreen.xib (Chinese (Traditional))` will be used.

If you want to change language programmatically you can use this in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate` :

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:@[@"ch"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"]; //en for english, fr for french, I think it's ch for chinese
```

I used `@[@"ch"]` because `AppleLanguages` is an array.

Comment: That's the problem here. Whenever a phone is in Chinese it will use the Chinese string file it however is not using my localized LaunchScreen.xib

Comment: @RutgerHuijsmans And what if you try using .string file instead of localized xib ? Does this work ?

Comment: Yea string file localizes just fine.

Comment: And with xib but not chinese language ? Maybe there's a bug with this language in xib files.